# Pronoun Reference usage

Tags: nouns, pronouns, reference, antecedents

Is it correct to use the pronoun reference **her** **before** introducing/specifying the name?
Is it called a vague pronoun reference?

Example:

> In **her** article, **Jane** provides a really good example of...

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice. Offhand I can't think of any nuance of difference between your version and the alternative *In **Jane's** article, **she** provides a really good example*. I couldn't even guess which sequence would be more common with this exact type of fronted adverbial clause - they both seem equally natural to me. But if the adverbial is moved to the *end* of the utterance, there is no choice - you can't say ***She** provides a really good example in **Jane's** article* unless ***she*** is someone else (already introduced in preceding text).

Comment: You have a [possessive antecedent](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/06/01/weekinreview/the-nation-parts-of-speech-the-bloody-crossroads-of-grammar-and-politics.html) — gets some people riled up. But I think you are really asking about using a pronoun before its noun referent. I think everyone is cool with that. *If **she** wanted to, **Jane** could provide a really good example of...* Look up *cataphora*.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is perfectly correct, and if you ask me, I would recommend using that than the alternative.

[Grammar.com](https://www.grammar.com/antecedents-placement-of-pronouns/) is very clear about this:

> When you use a pronoun, it will typically refer to a word somewhere close by. That is, the noun the pronoun replaces sits somewhere in the vicinity. This noun is called the ***antecedent***.
>
> The prefix *ante* (meaning *before*) might make you think that the word the pronoun refers to necessarily comes before the pronoun. But it doesn’t.
>
> True, ***a pronoun looks backward to its antecedent, but it can also look ahead to a referent placed later in the sentence***.
>
> The backward-looking pronouns are called ***anaphoric pronouns***.
>
> But a ***cataphoric*** (forward-looking) ***pronoun*** would find its referent coming later in the sentence:
>
> > After ***his*** discovery of New Zealand, ***Captain Cook*** went on to discover several Pacific islands. (This example appears in *New Fowler*, p. 134.)

In this example, you will find the cataphoric pronoun ***his***, referring (forward) to ***Captain Cook***, just as it is the case in your example.

The same article says that

> No rule states that a pronoun must refer to the immediately preceding noun.

and in order to support that, it quotes Mr. Burchfield, the editor of *New Fowler*, who expresses clearly the rule on placing pronouns:

> "It is clearly desirable that an anaphoric or cataphoric pronoun should be placed as near as the construction allows to the noun or noun phrase to which it refers, and in such a manner that there is no risk of ambiguity." (New Fowler, p. 629.)

So, indeed, ambiguity is the main concern when using pronouns. In your example which is not a complete sentence, no other referent than Jane can be *her*, so there is no ambiguity.

The good thing about cataphora is that it provokes a certain suspense: a pronoun triggers the search for its referent and when you use cataphora, the referent is expected with more tension. It is actually a rhetoric device.

Here is a good example:

> "After ***she*** declared ***herself*** 'broken, betrayed, at bay, really low' in another organ yesterday, I'm not sure the *Diary* should even mention poor ***Bel Mooney's*** name." (The Guardian, August 9, 1994 - quoted by [Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cataphora-grammar-1689829))

Answer (score -4):

### Sure

You don’t have to give people names if you don’t want.

> She reached into her bag and pulled out a mirror. Shutting out the world, she applied her lipstick, placed $20 on the table and walked out of Jake’s life.

Could be the start of an interesting novel.